# How I find limit of $P_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $a_1=1$ and $a_n=n(a_{n-1}+1)$ for $n=2,3,\dots$. Define $$P_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{a_1}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{a_2}\right)\dots\left(1+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)$$Find $$\lim_{n \to \infty}P_n$$

Trial: $$1+\frac{1}{a_n}=1+\frac{1}{n(a_{n-1}+1)}\;.$$
But I can't simplyfy.Please help.

Comment: Nice question. (+1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$a_{n+1}=(n+1)(a_n+1)=(n+1)a_n+(n+1)$, and so on, you can get that 
$$a_{n+1}=(n+1)!\left(1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}\right).$$
If that,$$P_n=1+\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!},$$
So $$\lim P_n=e.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Rewrite $P_n$ as:
$$P_n=\left(\frac{a_1+1}{a_1}\right)(\frac{a_2+1}{a_2})\cdots(\frac{a_n+1}{a_n})$$
$$P_n=\frac{1}{a_1}(\frac{a_1+1}{a_2})(\frac{a_2+1}{a_3})\cdots(\frac{a_{n-1}+1}{a_n})(a_n+1)$$
$$P_n=\frac{1}{a_1}(\frac{a_1+1}{a_2})(\frac{a_2+1}{a_3})\cdots(\frac{a_{n-1}+1}{a_n})(a_n+1)$$
$$P_n=\frac{1}{a_1}(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{3})\cdots(\frac{1}{n-1})(a_n+1)$$

Finally, solve the recurrence relation to get $a_n$

Comment: $$P_n=\frac{1}{a_1}(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{3})....(\frac{1}{n})(a_n+1)=\frac{a_{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

Comment: $a_{n+1}=(n+1)(a_n+1)=(n+1)a_n+(n+1)$, and so on,

Comment: I am afraid that, to the OP, the dificulty of the step *Finally, solve the recurrence relation to get $a_n$* is comparable to the dificulty of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

From the recurrence we get that $\frac{a_n}{n!}-\frac{a_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}$, that yields $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n!}=e$. Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_k+1}{a_k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_{k+1}}{(k+1)a_k}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=e $$